# c++ 11 equivalent of java atomiclongarray

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I am working on a C++ port of a Java library. One of the problems is I am not able to find equivalent of Java's AtomicLongArray. Anyone knows if there is anything already equivalent in c++ 11 or how to implement similar functionality? I had a look at C++11 atomics but could not find anything.

Comment: You'd greatly increase your potentially helpful audience if you explained what atomiclongarray is. That way you'd get help from people that knows C++, but not Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The docs for [AtomicLongArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLongArray.html) say:

> A long array in which elements may be updated atomically. See the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package specification for description of the properties of atomic variables.

That sounds to me like a simple array of `std::atomic<long>`:

```
std::array<std::atomic<long>, N> array;
// or, if size is not known at compile time
std::vector<std::atomic<long>> vector(n);
```

Note that only the elements are atomic, the container itself isn't, so don't go around `push_back`ing into the vector.

Comment: Question: how would you initialise an array of atomics? Otherwise, it's completely useless.

Comment: @Pippo like any other array.

Comment: Eh, but it doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434787/c-how-to-initialise-an-array-of-atomics

Comment: Why, yes, it does. That's the way you can initialise any other array.

Answer (score 0):

In [container.requirements.dataraces] the standard says

> -2- Notwithstanding (17.6.5.9), implementations are required to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in different elements in the same sequence, excepting `vector<bool>`, are modified concurrently.
>
> -3- [ *Note:* For a `vector<int> x` with a size greater than one, `x[1] = 5` and `*x.begin() = 10` can be executed concurrently without a data race, but `x[0] = 5` and `*x.begin() = 10` executed concurrently may result in a data race. As an exception to the general rule, for a `vector<bool> y, y[0] = true` may race with `y[1] = true`. *—end note* ]

So any container (except evil `vector<bool>`) allows separate elements to be updated without data races.  To also ensure updates to a single element are safe, use a container of atomic types, e.g. `std::vector<std::atomic<long>>`

Comment: Last time I checked you can't have vectors of atomic types since they don't have copy constructors.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003024/error-with-copy-constructor-assignment-operator-for-a-class-which-has-stdatomi

Comment: @SeanMcCauliff, that's not true, you can declare e.g. `std::vector<std::atomic<long>> v(10);` you just can't copy it or insert more elements into it.

Comment: //The following program produces over 500 lines of error messages when compling with gcc 4.7.2.  Is this an unimplemented feature in gcc?

#include <atomic>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<atomic<long>> atomicVector(10);
    return 0;
}

Comment: Never mind I forgot to add -std=c++11.  So you can't assign to a vector of atomic longs nor can you initialize them.  Go it.