# Error with copy constructor/assignment operator for a class which has std::atomic member variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I have a class like below.

```
#include <atomic>

static const long  myValue = 0;

class Sequence
{

public:

    Sequence(long initial_value = myValue) : value_(initial_value) {}


private:

     std::atomic<long> value_;
};

int main()
{
         Sequence firstSequence;
         Sequence secondSequence = firstSequence;
         return 0;
}
```

I am getting compilation error like this,

```
test.cpp:21:36: error: use of deleted function ‘Sequence::Sequence(const Sequence&)’
test.cpp:5:7: error: ‘Sequence::Sequence(const Sequence&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
test.cpp:5:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<long int>::atomic(const std::atomic<long int>&)’
```

Is that the default copy constructor and assignment opertaor do not work in such case?

PS: I am using gcc version 4.6.3

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't copy atomics with a standard copy constructor, since all loads and stores must happen explicitly. You'll have to write your own copy constructor for `Sequence` which does some initialization of the form `value_(rhs.value_.load())` (possibly with more relaxed memory ordering).

Comment: Can you edit and add a compiling code example? I fail to solve this problem, I have tried:

`Sequence& operator=(const Sequence &other)  { value_ = other.value_.load();    return *this; }`

Comment: @VictorLamoine: No idea what you did, but the general approach [works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZsHPDqhrIiybq7qf).

Comment: For more details on how you might actually write a copy-constructor (with default `seq_cst` for loading the source, but then avoiding the cost of an atomic store into the object under construction), see [Copy constructor for classes with atomic member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961043/copy-constructor-for-classes-with-atomic-member/46045691#46045691).  Make sure this is really what you want to implement; copying around atomics is usually contrary to their purpose as shared state.

Answer (score 11):

Atomic has deleted copy-ctor. So copy/move-ctors in your class are deleted.

n3337 12.8/11

> An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is an inline public member of its class. A defaulted copy/
> move constructor for a class X is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if X has:
>
> **— a non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot be copied/moved because
> overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s corresponding constructor, results in an ambiguity or a
> function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted constructor,**

Answer (score 8):

Because there is no `std::atomic<long int>::atomic(const std::atomic<long int>&)` function, there is no way for the compiler to create a default copy constructor for the `Sequence` class. If you need a copy constructor for that class (and you do if you want `Sequence secondSequence = firstSequence;` to work) then you need to write one.

This behavior is required by the standard:

> The atomic integral and address types are listed below. These types shall have standard layout. They shall have a trivial default constructor, A constexpr explicit value constructor, **a deleted copy constructor**, a deleted copy assignment operator, and a trivial destructor. These types shall support aggregate initialization syntax.

Answer (score 5):

I'd guess that choice to delete the copy constructor in the standard was for two reasons:

- a load/store pair is required in general.  Is there any way to enforce that this would be done when you don't control the callers of std::atomic?
- What do you do if std::atomic<> type that you were using was one for which is_lock_free() is false (ie. a mutex is required in the implementation for that size integer type)?  What copy semantics do you use for the mutex initialization?  A mutex that ends up implicitly copied needs to be re-initialized since it could be unluckily copied in a locked state.  I'd guess that std::mutex also has a deleted copy constructor because of this, and that pushes the requirement into std::atomic too.