# C++11 Thread Safety of Atomic Containers

Tags: multithreading, c++11, containers, atomic

I am trying to implement a thread safe STL vector without mutexes. So I followed through [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16920528/3458969) post and implemented a wrapper for the atomic primitives.

However when I ran the code below, it displayed out `Failed!`twice from the below code (only two instances of race conditions) so it doesn't seem to be thread safe. I'm wondering how can I fix that?

**Wrapper Class**

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct AtomicVariable
{
    std::atomic<T> atomic;

    AtomicVariable() : atomic(T()) {}

    explicit AtomicVariable(T const& v) : atomic(v) {}
    explicit AtomicVariable(std::atomic<T> const& a) : atomic(a.load()) {}

    AtomicVariable(AtomicVariable const&other) : 
        atomic(other.atomic.load()) {}

    inline AtomicVariable& operator=(AtomicVariable const &rhs) {
        atomic.store(rhs.atomic.load());
        return *this;
    }

    inline AtomicVariable& operator+=(AtomicVariable const &rhs) {
        atomic.store(rhs.atomic.load() + atomic.load());
        return *this;
    }

    inline bool operator!=(AtomicVariable const &rhs) {
        return !(atomic.load() == rhs.atomic.load());
    }
};

typedef AtomicVariable<int>    AtomicInt;
```

**Functions and Testing**

```cpp
// Vector of 100 elements.
vector<AtomicInt> common(100, AtomicInt(0));

void add10(vector<AtomicInt> &param){
    for (vector<AtomicInt>::iterator it = param.begin();
        it != param.end(); ++it){
        *it += AtomicInt(10);
    }
}

void add100(vector<AtomicInt> &param){
    for (vector<AtomicInt>::iterator it = param.begin();
        it != param.end(); ++it){
        *it += AtomicInt(100);
    }
}

void doParallelProcessing(){

    // Create threads
    std::thread t1(add10, std::ref(common));
    std::thread t2(add100, std::ref(common));

    // Join 'em
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    // Print vector again
    for (vector<AtomicInt>::iterator it = common.begin();
        it != common.end(); ++it){
        if (*it != AtomicInt(110)){
            cout << "Failed!" << endl;
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Just for testing purposes
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        // Reset vector
        common.clear();
        common.resize(100, AtomicInt(0));
        doParallelProcessing();
    }
}
```

Is there such a thing as an atomic container? I've also tested this with a regular `vector<int>` it didn't have any `Failed` output but that might just be a coincidence.

Comment: Your `AtomicVariable` is not just pointless - it's actively harmful. It takes an `std::atomic`, and makes some of its operations non-atomic. In particular, `std::atomic<int>::operator+=` is atomic, while `AtomicInt::operator+=` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write operator += as:

```
    inline AtomicVariable& operator+=(AtomicVariable const &rhs) {
        atomic += rhs.atomic;
        return *this;
    }
```

In documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic operator += is atomic.

Your example fails because below scenario of execution is possible:

1. Thread1 - rhs.atomic.load() - returns 10 ; Thread2 - rhs.atomic.load() - returns 100
2. Thread1 - atomic.load() - returns 0 ; Thread2 - atomic.load - returns 0
3. Thread1 - add values (0 + 10 = 10) ; Thread2 - add values (0 + 100)
4. Thread1 - atomic.store(10) ; Thread2 - atomic.store(100)

Finally in this case in atomic value might be 10 or 100, depends of which thread first execute atomic.store.

Comment: Or, for that matter, just drop `AtomicVariable` and use `std::atomic<int>` directly. The wrapper appears to be completely pointless.

Comment: Looking into this right now. @IgorTandetnik it is required because there is no implicit conversion for operators. May be I've coded wrong but I've tried doing with std::atomic<int> it didn't compile.

Comment: @JohnJohn Have `AtomicVariable::operator+=` call the underlying `atomic::operator+=`. As in `atomic += rhs.atomic.load()`. Or `atomic.fecth_add(rhs.atomic.load())`. This should help.

Comment: Read the documentation at [`this link`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/fetch_add/) did not know that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

please note that

```
           atomic.store(rhs.atomic.load() + atomic.load());
```

is **not** atomic

You have two options to solve it.
memoery
1) Use a mutex.

**EDIT** as T.C mentioned in the comments this is irrelevant since the operation here will be load() then load() then store() (not relaxed mode) - so memory order is not related here.

2) Use memory order http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/12/01/c-atomics-and-memory-ordering/

> memory_order_acquire: guarantees that subsequent loads are not moved before the current load or any preceding loads.
>   memory_order_release: preceding stores are not moved past the current store or any subsequent stores.

I'm still not sure about 2, but I think if the stores will not be on parallel, it will work.

Comment: This makes no sense. Yes, you show two instructions - but each touches its own separate memory location. For something to be "not atomic", there should be two reads and/or modifications of the same memory location. The real problem is in `operator+=`: `atomic.store(rhs.atomic.load() + atomic.load());` This calls `load` and `store` on the same atomic.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - The two instruction are the problem. if the order is T1 load T2 load T2 store T1 load there's a problem as they touch the same memory.

Comment: I do not understand your notation. In any case, your example loads from one piece of memory and stores to another; they do not "touch the same memory".

Comment: So what exactly do you mean by "not atomic" here? What can change between what and what else? I don't understand the scenario that you feel poses a problem.

Comment: 1) Read again the comment. 2) The function += is not atomic, as implies from my answer. either way, the other answer (as well as your comment) is more correct

Comment: Yes, `+=` is not atomic. But you seem to be pointing to `operator=`, not `operator+=`, as the culprit - and I don't see anything wrong with `operator=`. In fact, `std::atomic<T>::operator=` does precisely the same thing.

Comment: The vague handwaving about memory order is useless and also wrong. By default `std::atomic` already uses the strongest memory order there is (`memory_order_seq_cst`).