# Cannot synchronize std::thread via std::vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, compiler-optimization, thread-synchronization

## Code

I've got an algorithm to run using threads.
When several parts of the algorithm are coming to a specific step, I want the main thread to know this.
I work under Xubuntu 18.04.

Code of the main application follows this scheme

```
vector<thread> threads;
vector<bool> flags;
bool finish = false;
cout << "Create" << endl;
create_threads(threads, flags, finish);
cout << "Finish" << endl;
finish = true;
cout << "Destroy" << endl;
destroy_threads(threads);
cout << "End" << endl;
return 0;
```

Each thread loops until the `finish` is `true`
(it's changed by the main thread from the outside).
Also, after the creation of the threads, I check whether they have come to a specific step by assigning `flags[thread_number] = true`

```
void create_threads(vector<thread>& threads, vector<bool>& flags, bool& finish)
{
    auto command = [&finish, &flags](unsigned thread_number)
    {
        while (!finish)
        {
            flags[thread_number] = true;
        }
    };
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < threads_count; ++i)
    {
        flags.push_back(false);
        threads.push_back(move(thread{command, i}));
    }
    // BUG: Freeze is here
    wait_threads(flags);
    // BUG: Freeze is here
}
```

I've got a function for the check.
It just waits until all elements of the `flags` vector are `true`.
Before threads execution, they all are `false`, and only threads modify them.

```
void wait_threads(vector<bool>& flags)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (all_of(flags.begin(), flags.end(), [](bool value) { return value; }))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The entire code example looks as follows and can be compiled with `clang++ sync.cpp -lpthread -o sync`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

const unsigned threads_count = 2;

/**
 * Wait for threads to start.
 * Every thread has an access to the `flags` vector.
 * After the initialization each thread assigns `true`
 * to each component of the vector.
 *
 * Though, with `-O2` and `-O3` optimization flags
 * the function `wait_threads` freezes,
 * like the elements don't change from `false` to `true`.
 */
void wait_threads(vector<bool>& flags)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (all_of(flags.begin(), flags.end(), [](bool value) { return value; }))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Create threads.
 * After the launch, each thread assigns `true` to the corresponding `flag` cell.
 * Also, the threads watch `finish` variable to stop when it's `true`.
 */
void create_threads(vector<thread>& threads, vector<bool>& flags, bool& finish)
{
    auto command = [&finish, &flags](unsigned thread_number)
    {
        while (!finish)
        {
            flags[thread_number] = true;
        }
    };
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < threads_count; ++i)
    {
        flags.push_back(false);
        threads.push_back(move(thread{command, i}));
    }
    // BUG: Freeze is here
    wait_threads(flags);
    // BUG: Freeze is here
}

/**
 * Wait until all threads finish.
 */
void destroy_threads(vector<thread>& threads)
{
    for (auto& el : threads)
    {
        el.join();
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<thread> threads;
    vector<bool> flags;
    bool finish = false;
    cout << "Create" << endl;
    create_threads(threads, flags, finish);
    cout << "Finish" << endl;
    finish = true;
    cout << "Destroy" << endl;
    destroy_threads(threads);
    cout << "End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## Issue

When I compile the code without any optimization, it runs well.
If I use `-O2`, `-O3` or `-Ofast`, it freezes on the `wait_threads` call.
Looks like the compiler sees that the `flags` vector is populated with `false` in the main thread, and remembers it. It happens even with `const unsigned threads_count = 1;`.
I've tried to use `vector< atomic<unsigned> >`, but I've found the [How to declare a vector of atomic in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13194652/1305036) question, and understood that this is tricky and is not the right way to solve the problem.

## Appendix (The real code)

Check in the real code are more complicated. Here is the real waiting function

```
void wait_threads_change(
    ULONG beginning,
    vector<ULONG>* last_changes,
    vector<ULONG>* last_checks
)
{
    while (*std::min_element(last_checks->begin(), last_checks->end()) <= beginning)
    {
        // cout << flush; // WORKAROUND: This helps to avoid freeze
    }
    while (
        (*std::min_element(last_checks->begin(), last_checks->end())
        <= *std::max_element(last_changes->begin(), last_changes->end()))
    )
    {
    }
}
```

and the real thread creation

```
void run_csp_threads(
    struct ConstraintGraph *graph,
    vector<thread>* threads,
    vector<ULONG>* last_changes,
    vector<ULONG>* last_checks,
    BOOL& finish
)
{
    const ULONG THREADS = 7;
    auto command = ([graph, THREADS, last_changes, last_checks, &finish](ULONG thread_number)
    {
        while (!finish)
        {
            if (csp_solution_iteration(graph, THREADS, thread_number))
            {
                do
                {
                    (*last_changes)[thread_number] = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
                } while (csp_solution_iteration(graph, THREADS, thread_number));
            }
            else
            {
                (*last_checks)[thread_number] = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
            }
        }
    });
    ULONG beginning = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    for (ULONG thread_number = 0; thread_number < THREADS; ++thread_number)
    {
        last_changes->push_back(beginning);
        last_checks->push_back(beginning);
        threads->push_back(move(thread{command, thread_number}));
    }
    wait_threads_change(beginning, last_changes, last_checks);
}
```

For the question I've tried to simplify the code as much as I can to know how to solve at least one problem.

Comment: `while (!finish)` This is UB. `finish` isn't atomic so your compiler most likely optimizes this to check only once.

Comment: You really need to read up on the basics of thread safety in C++. You're also somewhat lucky that you are using `std::vector<bool>`, because that makes it much easier to trip over the UB in your code.

Comment: @MaxLanghof @tkausl, but earlier versions of `C++` don't have `atomic`. Does it mean that there I could use ordinary variables, and new standard needs `atomic` to work well in this case?

Comment: @Charlie Earlier C++ standards did not define memory model that included multithreading, so you couldn't rely on the C++ standard there but your compiler documentation instead.

Comment: You will also need `std::vector<std::atomic<bool>>` to be the type for your `flags` variable.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot in the question I've noticed that it cannot be done directly, so I've decided that it's not the right way to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13194652/1305036