# Is pointer to atomic thread safe?

Tags: c++, concurrency, stdatomic

Here is an example:

This is safe:

```
std::atomic_int i;

// Thread 1
i = 4;

// Thread 2
std::cout << i.load();
```

But is this safe to write:

```
std::atomic_int *i = new std::atomic_int;

// Thread 1
*i = 4;

// Thread 2
std::count << (*i).load();
```

My main rationale is that I want to have vector of atomics. Since atomics are not CopyConstructible, I need pointers to atomics to store into vector.

Comment: No it's not safe, because the pointer itself is not atomic. Only the object that the variable is pointing to.

Comment: But if one never changes the value of the actual pointer (you can actually declare it as const pointer), are the underlying stores/loads still atomic? I think they definitely are.

Otherwise there is no way to have vector of atomics unless you use pointers to atomics.

Comment: If you can 100% guarantee that the pointer variable itself won't be modified, then yes the loads and stores are just the same. You're still using the atomic object the same.

Comment: If there's a happens-before relationship between the completion of the assignment to the pointer and to reading the pointer on the threads, there's no problem. If there isn't, you've got a problem. In addition you also need a happens-before relationship between the last operation on the dereferenced pointer object on the threads and the destruction of the object...

Comment: On a different note, instead of `(*i).load()`, why not `i->load()`?

Comment: Note that the code shown can still result in undefined behaviour, since the atomic is not guaranteed to be initialized with a value before `i.load()` on thread 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a vector of atomic in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193484/how-to-declare-a-vector-of-atomic-in-c)

Comment: Thank you @fabian, I understand that and will be careful about it. Unfortunately this question does not help me that much, because I don't want a custom ad-hoc wrapper class. I just want to use standard atomic class from standard library

Comment: Do you have a C++-20 implementation? If so, you can use a vector of integers and work with them via `std::atomic_ref`. If not, you can go with another container that does not require a copy/move constructor when adding elements (such as `std::deque`). Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/8nrh41T6c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's safe, assuming that `new std::atomic_int` happens before both threads are started (or the access to the pointer itself is synchronized in some other way).

Note that before C++20 atomics are not zeroed by default, so if `.load()` happened before the write, it would cause UB.