# List of objects with atomic objects

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to maintain a container (list or vector) of objects that have atomics as member variables. It seems to be creating compile errors I am not sure how to fix. The messages I see are deleted copy constructor for atomics.
How can I work around that?
I will need to add to the list (or vector)

```
#include <atomic>
#include <list>

struct S {
    std::atomic<int> n_{0};
};

int main() {
    std::list<S> l1;
    std::list<S> l2 = l1; // compile error
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<S>> l;
    S s1;
    auto ss1 = std::make_shared<S>(s1); // compile error
    
}
```

Comment: Why do you make `s1` at all? Why not just `auto ss1 = std::make_shared<S>();` and have it construct it directly into the shared pointer?

Comment: Sounds like a dup or near-dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12003024/4641116

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need the `shared_ptr` at all, you can construct the object directly into the list:

```
std::list<S> l1;
l1.emplace_back();
// l1 now has one element default-constructed
```

You can however not copy such a list, but it seems unlikely that you'd want that semantically anyway.