# Why is copy assignment of volatile std::atomics allowed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, stdatomic

`std::atomic` has deleted [copy assignment operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator%3D). Hence, the following results in a compiler error:

```
std::atomic<int> a1, a2;
a1 = a2; // Error
```

I think the motivation for the deleted operators is explained e.g. [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12003024/3740047). So far, so good.
But I noticed, that adding `volatile` causes the code to compile suddenly (live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bMKTcqjo6)):

```
volatile std::atomic<int> a1, a2;
a1 = a2; // OK
```

I do not really require `volatile` variables for my project, so this is just out of curiosity: Is this an oversight in the C++ standard, or is this deliberate (why?)?

Note: I can get a compiler error by hacking the `std::atomic` definition, either by adding

```
atomic & operator=(const volatile atomic &) volatile = delete;
```

or by removing the [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T) `operator T() const volatile noexcept`.

Comment: How do you even come to this? Never in a million years I would have tried to put `volatile` upfront.

Comment: If you look at the asm, we see it's calling `std::__atomic_base<int>::operator int() const volatile` and `operator=(int)`.  So it's converting to `int` and back, not actually doing copy-assignment directly between atomics.  IDK why that can happen with `volatile` but not without, or if the ISO standard even allows it, but it would be surprising if all 3 major compilers had the same bug.  (including clang with `-stdlib=libc++`, vs. gcc with `libstdc++` vs. MSVC's own headers.)

Comment: [LWG 908](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2992.htm#LWG908) explains _why_ adding the `volatile` qualifier induces the observed difference: the copy-assignment operator being `volatile` is kind of a hack to make the compiler prefer one conversion chain to another in `a1=0`. Now, has the committee foreseen the consequence OP found there? This is the question.

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri Well, I found this interesting piece while specializing `std::atomic` for a custom type which implements some simple fixed point arithmetic. It is just a wrapper around an integer. I started the implementation by going through the cppreference documentation from the top. When implementing the assignments, I added a compile time unit test to check that the volatile assignment does NOT compile (simply via a `requires`). I was surprised when that very test failed later on, namely once I added the conversion `operator T() const volatile`, and got curious. Hence the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [LWG3633](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3633).

---

`std::atomic<T>` has a (deleted) copy assignment operator taking a `const atomic<T>&` (1), an assignment operator function taking a `T` (2), and a (non-explicit) conversion function to `T` (3):

```cpp
// (1)
atomic& operator=(const atomic&) = delete;
atomic& operator=(const atomic&) volatile = delete;

// (2)
T operator=(T) noexcept;
T operator=(T) volatile noexcept;

// (3)
operator T() const noexcept;
operator T() const volatile noexcept;
```

When the assignment source is a non-volatile `std::atomic<T>`, both assignment operator functions are viable, but (1) is preferred because it does not require a user-defined conversion on the right operand.

When the right operand is volatile, (1) is not viable because `const atomic<T>&` cannot bind to a volatile glvalue, so (2) is chosen.