# AVX512 Compare and Swap

Tags: x86, avx, compare-and-swap, avx512

Is there an atomic CAS instruction or equivalent in the AVX512 set?

I can't immediately find one but don't have the best google fu.

Comment: I don't think so - what are you actually trying to achieve ? I can't think of a use case where you'd want an atomic SIMD compare-and-swap (presumably element-wise ?) ?

Comment: @PaulR I was thinking about lockless data structures, e.g. CASing multiple packed 64bit ints simultaneously.  The specific idea I had (if an atomic 512bit CAS was possible) was a trie with 256bits of mask for existence and 256bits for 4 pointers in order of existence in the mask.

Comment: If you use 32-bit pointers (or 32-bit array offsets relative to a 64-bit base pointer), you can fit twice as many elements in the same vector.  But atomic 64-byte loads aren't possible either (again without a transaction), so even readers of this data structure would need expensive operations.  Unless you only need it to work on a specific Skylake-AVX512 machine, where aligned 64-byte loads/stores may in fact be atomic even though x86 on paper does *not* guarantee this.  (And some future AMD CPU will probably run 512-bit ops as multiple smaller loads/stores.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than `lock cmpxchg16b` (16-bytes), x86 doesn't have any guaranteed-atomic operations wider than 8 bytes.  Aligned vector load / store are elementwise-atomic on current CPUs (i.e. no tearing within an 8-byte element), [although it's not clear if the documentation guarantees that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012574/per-element-atomicity-of-vector-load-store-and-gather-scatter).

Were you hoping for a 64-byte whole-cache-line CAS?  There's no single instruction for that.

AVX512 alone doesn't provide that, but with [TSX (transactional memory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_Synchronization_Extensions) you can roll your own.  Put a load + compare + store inside a transaction.  IDK how expensive `xbegin` / `xend` is compared to `lock cmpxchg`.

You don't need AVX512 for it either; the whole transaction commits atomically or not at all, so you could use a pair of AVX2 load / compare instructions to implement a 64-byte CAS.

Comment: Thanks for information :)
Shame that it's not possible without TSX (I've experimented with TSX before and found it to have far too high of an overhead to be viable currently).

Comment: @AlexR: Indeed, it would be nice if there was some way to query what width of operation is atomic on the current CPU, so you could take advantage of atomic 64-byte loads on CPUs where the actually *are* atomic.  (That wouldn't give you atomic CAS, but it would make the read path cheap.)  I guess it would be interesting if there were SIMD atomics, there are no SIMD RMW instructions, so the load/store execution units don't currently need any support for read-modify-write on the FP side, only integer.

Comment: Also, that might constrain chipsets if cache-line transfers between cores had to be atomic.  They are on normal Intel machines, but maybe exotic machines with more than 8 sockets might use custom glue logic...  AMD CPUs in practice can have tearing on cache line transfers even when within a single socket a vector store is atomic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646018/sse-instructions-which-cpus-can-do-atomic-16b-memory-operations/7647825#7647825

Comment: I'm curious to know why, if `lock` prefix locks the whole cache line, can't we lock the cache line, execute arbitrary instructions, then unlock it when we're done?

Comment: @NickStrupat: Because that could deadlock the hardware if software used it wrong.  Automatically locking only for a single instruction doesn't have that problem.  However, TSX (transactional memory) *does* provide what you're asking for, across potentially multiple line.  (With a transactional abort on conflict, not deadlock, but that means software has to be aware of the need to maybe retry, and provide a branch address.)  Similarly, on other architectures, LL/SC does let you do arbitrary things to one memory location as an atomic RMW, but not a whole line.)

Comment: @NickStrupat: Also, hanging on to exclusive ownership of a cache line as part of the `lock` prefix makes this part of the operation atomic; getting this cache line to other cores as a whole 64-byte atomic transfer is another matter.  (Of course, it appears Intel CPUs do that, too, but there are counterexamples of CPUs that [introduce tearing in the transfer between cores on different sockets, but fine within one socket, e.g. AMD K10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646018/sse-instructions-which-cpus-can-do-atomic-16b-memory-operations/7647825#7647825) which used HyperTransport for that.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Interesting... that makes perfect sense. Thank you for the concise explanation!

Comment: @NickStrupat if you only need interrupt atomicity you could try out [rseq](https://github.com/compudj/librseq).