# Is assigning a pointer in C program considered atomic on x86-64

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, x86-64, atomic

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Types.html#Atomic-Types says - *In practice, you can assume that int is atomic. You can also assume that pointer types are atomic; that is very convenient. Both of these assumptions are true on all of the machines that the GNU C Library supports and on all POSIX systems we know of.*

My question is whether pointer assignment can be considered atomic on x86_64 architecture for a C program compiled with gcc m64 flag. OS is 64bit Linux and CPU is  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU D-1548. One thread will be setting a pointer and another thread accessing the pointer. There is only one writer thread and one reader thread. Reader should either be getting the previous value of the pointer or the latest value and no garbage value in between.

If it is not considered atomic, please let me know how can I use the gcc atomic builtins or maybe memory barrier like __sync_synchronize to achieve the same without using locks. Interested only in C solution and not C++. Thanks!

Comment: First, there are almost certainly ways to make modifications to a pointer non-atomic even on x86 hardware - `packed` jumps out immediately.  Second, if you're wrong, you've just introduced a wonderful little [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) that you will **never** find.  In short, **never** "assume".

Comment: The link seems to refer to atomicity between a signal handler and a baseline thread [on the _same_ CPU] and _not_ between threads on multiple cores. You'll need some primitives from `atomic.h`. But, even with atomic access, how does the reader thread _know_ when the writer thread has posted a new value? The reader could loop on _stale_ values. You need some other sync mechanism (e.g. `sem_wait/sem_post`) or a sequence number or other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bear in mind that atomicity alone is not enough for communicating between threads. Nothing prevents the [compiler](https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/) and [CPU](https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/) from reordering previous/subsequent load and store instructions with that "atomic" store. In old days people used `volatile` to prevent that reordering but that was never intended for use with threads and doesn't provide means to specify less or more restrictive [memory order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order) (see "Relationship with `volatile`" in there).

You should use C11 atomics because they guarantee both atomicity and memory order.

Comment: Usually people that want to avoid `#include <stdatomic.h>` and `_Atomic` want that because they think it's less efficient.  `memory_order_relaxed` usually compiles to the same asm as you could get with `volatile` and/or` asm("" ::: "memory")` barriers to make things safe (non-portably, on a specific implementation) without `_Atomic`.  Related: [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535118) - as you say, never.

Answer (score 4):

**A plain global `char *ptr` should *not* be considered atomic.**  It might work sometimes, especially with optimization disabled, but you can get the compiler to make safe and efficient optimized asm by using modern language features to tell it you want atomicity.

Use [C11 `stdatomic.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) or GNU C [`__atomic` builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html).  And see [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86) - yes the underlying asm operations are atomic "for free", but you need to control the compiler's code-gen to get sane behaviour for multithreading.

See also LWN: [Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?](https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/) - weird effects of using plain vars include several really bad well-known things, but also more obscure stuff like invented loads, reading a variable more than once if the compiler decides to optimize away a local tmp and load the shared var twice, instead of loading it into a register.  Using `asm("" ::: "memory")` compiler barriers may not be sufficient to defeat that depending on where you put them.

**So use proper atomic stores and loads that tell the compiler what you want:**  You should generally use atomic loads to read them, too.

```
#include <stdatomic.h>            // C11 way
_Atomic char *c11_shared_var;     // all access to this is atomic, functions needed only if you want weaker ordering

void foo(){
   atomic_store_explicit(&c11_shared_var, newval, memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

```
char *plain_shared_var;       // GNU C
// This is a plain C var.  Only specific accesses to it are atomic; be careful!

void foo() {
   __atomic_store_n(&plain_shared_var, newval, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
}
```

Using `__atomic_store_n` on a plain var is the functionality that C++20 `atomic_ref` exposes.  If multiple threads access a variable for the entire time that it needs to exist, you might as well just use C11 stdatomic because every access needs to be atomic (not optimized into a register or whatever).  When you want to let the compiler load once and reuse that value, do `char *tmp = c11_shared_var;` (or `atomic_load_explicit` if you only want acquire instead of seq_cst; cheaper on a few non-x86 ISAs).

---

**Besides lack of tearing (atomicity of asm load or store), the other key parts of `_Atomic foo *` are:**

- **The compiler will assume that other threads may have changed memory contents** (like `volatile` effectively implies), otherwise the assumption of no data-race UB will let the compiler hoist loads out of loops.    Without this, dead-store elimination might only do one store at the end of a loop, not updating the value multiple times.

  The read side of the problem is usually what bites people in practice, see [Multithreading program stuck in optimized mode but runs normally in -O0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516052/multithreading-program-stuck-in-optimized-mode-but-runs-normally-in-o0) - e.g. `while(!flag){}` becomes `if(!flag) infinite_loop;` with optimization enabled.
- **Ordering wrt. other code.**  e.g. you can use `memory_order_release` to make sure that other threads that see the pointer update also see all changes to the pointed-to data.  (On x86 that's as simple as compile-time ordering, no extra barriers needed for acquire/release, only for seq_cst.  Avoid seq_cst if you can; `mfence` or `lock`ed operations are slow.)
- *Guarantee* that the store will compile to a single asm instruction.  You'd be depending on this.  It does happen in practice with sane compilers, although it's conceivable that a compiler might decide to use `rep movsb` to copy a few contiguous pointers, and that some machine somewhere might have a microcoded implementation that does some stores narrower than 8 bytes.

  (This failure mode is highly unlikely; the Linux kernel relies on `volatile` load/store compiling to a single instruction with GCC / clang for its hand-rolled intrinsics.  But if you just used `asm("" ::: "memory")` to make sure a store happened on a non-`volatile` variable, there's a chance.)

Also, **something like `ptr++` will compile to an atomic RMW operation** like `lock add qword [mem], 4`, rather than separate load and store like `volatile` would. (See [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num) for more about atomic RMWs).  Avoid that if you don't need it, it's slower.  e.g. `atomic_store_explicit(&ptr, ptr + 1, mo_release);` - seq_cst loads are cheap on x86-64 but seq_cst stores aren't.

Also note that memory barriers can't create atomicity (lack of tearing), they can only create *ordering* wrt other ops.

In practice x86-64 ABIs do have `alignof(void*) = 8` so all pointer objects should be naturally aligned (except in a `__attribute__((packed))` struct which violates the ABI, so you can use `__atomic_store_n` on them.  It should compile to what you want (plain store, no overhead), and meet the asm requirements to be atomic.

See also [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118) - you can roll your own atomics with `volatile` and asm memory barriers, but don't.  The Linux kernel does that, but it's a lot of effort for basically no gain, especially for a user-space program.

---

Side note: an often repeated misconception is that `volatile` or `_Atomic` are needed to avoid reading stale values *from cache*.  This is *not* the case.

All machines that run C11 threads across multiple cores have coherent caches, not needing explicit flush instructions in the reader or writer.  Just ordinary load or store instructions, like x86 `mov`.  The key is to not let the compiler keep values of shared variable in CPU *registers* (which are thread-private).  It normally can do this optimization because of the assumption of no data-race Undefined Behaviour.  Registers are very much not the same thing as L1d CPU cache; managing what's in registers vs. memory is done by the compiler, while hardware keeps cache in sync.  See [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118) for more details about why coherent caches is sufficient to make `volatile` work like `memory_order_relaxed`.

See [Multithreading program stuck in optimized mode but runs normally in -O0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516052/multithreading-program-stuck-in-optimized-mode-but-runs-normally-in-o0) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

For almost all architectures, pointer load and store are atomic.  A once notable exception was 8086/80286 where pointers could be seg:offset; there was an l[des]s instruction which could make an atomic load; but no corresponding atomic store.

The integrity of the pointer is only a small concern; your bigger issue revolves around synchronization:  the pointer was at value Y, you set it to X; how will you know when nobody is using the (old) Y value?
A somewhat related problem is that you may have stored things at X, which the *other* thread expects to find.  Without synchronization, *other* might see the new pointer value, however what it points to might not be up to date yet.

Answer (score -1):

"Atomic" is treated as this quantum state where something can be both atomic and not atomic at the same time because "it's possible" that "some machines" "somewhere" "might not" write "a certain value" atomically. Maybe.

That is not the case. Atomicity has a very specific meaning, and it solves a very specific problem: threads being pre-empted by the OS to schedule another thread in its place on that core. And you cannot stop a thread from executing mid-assembly instruction.

What that means is that any single assembly instruction is "atomic" by definition. And since you have registry moving instructions, any register-sized copy is atomic by definition. That means a 32-bit integer on a 32-bit CPU, and a 64-bit integer on a 64-bit CPU are all atomic -- and of course that includes pointers (ignore all the people who will tell you "some architectures" have pointers of "different size" than registers, that hasn't been the case since 386).

You should however be careful not to hit variable caching problems (ie one thread writing a pointer, and another trying to read it but getting an old value from the cache), use `volatile` as needed to prevent this.

Comment: *What that means is that any single assembly instruction is "atomic" by definition*  The problem is in **proving** that one line of C code will **always** be translated into a single instruction.  You can never do that.

Comment: Not trying to prove that, only that reading or writing an integer (or a pointer) is atomic. Whatever operations you do on it aren't.

Comment: "Any single assembly instruction is atomic by definition": Again, depending on your definition.  A read-modify-write instruction like `add mem, reg` is atomic in the sense that it won't be interrupted on its own core, but non-atomic in the sense that another core could write that location in between the "read" and "write" parts of the instruction.  I realize that is not the issue here but the sentence could be misleading out of context.

Comment: Yes, you are.  You are implicitly assuming loads or stores generated by a compiler to implement your C code will be done in a single instruction.  And even by doing that, ordering and visibility guarantees of atomic operations are ignored.

Comment: *getting an old value from the cache* - no, that isn't the problem.  It's getting an old value *from a register*, assuming that memory hasn't changed.  i.e. turning `while(!flag){}` into `if(!flag){ infinite_loop; }` by hoisting a non-atomic / non-volatile load.  All real-world C11 thread implementations run on hardware with coherent caches, please stop spreading this mis-conception that cache can be stale as the explanation for why you need `_Atomic` or `volatile`.

Comment: (In theory you could possibly implement C11 on a machine that needed explicit flush instructions even on `relaxed` operations to make a store visible "in a reasonable amount of time", but in practice if you have a heterogeneous ARM with microcontroller + DSP or something that aren't coherent, you don't run threads of the same program across those cores.)

Comment: I agree with @AndrewHenle; use `atomic_store_explicit(&var, value, memory_order_relaxed)` to make sure you get a single-instruction store, as recommended in [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36624881).  This has the advantage over `volatile` that you can use `mo_release` to make sure that store is ordered after stores to the pointed-to data, and that ISO C11 guarantees the correctness of your program, rather than mostly unwritten rules and assumptions that roll-your-own atomics (like the Linux kernel's) depend on.

Comment: Re “And you cannot stop a thread from executing mid-assembly instruction”: Some processors have interruptible instructions. Not likely a compiler would use them for updating a stored pointer, but it shows the incorrectness and hazard of making assumptions like this. ARM has interruptible load/store multiple register instructions, and somebody (I forget whether VAX, IBM, or Intel) has an interruptible copy-bytes instruction.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: x86-64 `rep movsb` (memcpy in a can) is interruptible.  Compilers do sometimes inline `rep movsb` for small fixed-size copies, or at least used to, but it's rare these days because SIMD load/store avoids microcode startup overhead.  (Unless Ice Lake's "fast short rep" feature changes that tuning heuristic.) But yes it's conceivable that a compiler could decide to basically memcpy a couple pointers, including the one you care about, and that some CPU might execute it internally as narrower than 8-byte stores.  (e.g. with the "fast strings" control reg bit cleared)

Comment: So many "in theory", "could be" and "some processors" and whatnot. None of us are talking about those processors, none of us are talking about `rep movsb` (since I specifically said register-sized variables), and so on. Armchair systems designers aside, what this guy is trying to do doesn't need explicit atomic support from the x86/x86_64 instruction set, and none of us care about your other processors.

Comment: @Blindy Are you saying that if my code does `c = 0; d = 0; c = 1;` it can't be changed by the compiler to `c = 0; d = 0; c++;`? Or `c = 0; d = 0; c = d + 1;`? Where do I find this guarantee?

Comment: @Blindy: Right, it doesn't need any special x86-64 *asm*, you just need special C syntax to make sure you get the right asm.  `volatile` is not the recommended way, and is kind of a dead-end path because as soon as you need any ordering stronger than `relaxed`, you'd need to use inline asm or switch to something else.

Comment: The `rep movsb` example was for a compiler compiling assignments to multiple plain `char *` objects that *happen* to be adjacent into one `rep movsb`.  e.g. if they're in a struct or array, or the compiler just happens to know that globals are adjacent.  GCC in practice *does* merge `=` assignments to adjacent struct members so you could expect a `movaps` or even unaligned `movups` for setting multiple pointers in a struct.  In practice we're sure those are [at least per-element atomic on real CPUs, but there's no documented guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46012574/224132).

Comment: But yes, the `rep movsb` possible problem is mostly hypothetical, not a practical concern I think.  Still, the same language features that give other good stuff also prevent that problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, real programming isn't about theoretical questions or fear or whatever else drives you, it's easy to check exactly what's going on: https://godbolt.org/z/jaYYMW (all 3 atomic assignments, in case you can't tell). I will try to make this as clear as I can: your theoretical questions hold absolutely no value to me.

Comment: @PeterCordes, that's fine, let it optimize its heart away, that's still atomic, documented or not. Everything else is theoretical at best.

Comment: Something that happens to work in one case doesn't prove it for the general case.  That's part of what makes debugging, testing, and reasoning about lockless code hard.  Different surrounding code could create problems.  I suggest you read this LWN article: [Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?](https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/) which points out multiple real-word gotchas that can happen with GCC.

Comment: @Blindy I've been a real programmer for several decades now and I've gotten severely burned too many times by assuming that future optimizers wouldn't make particular transformations to my code. What you're suggesting people do -- assume particular future optimizations will not be possible or likely -- is a recipe for disaster. And for what? Using appropriate atomic operations has *no* performance cost and makes the code easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Is there any document that fully and accurately describes the language that the authors of clang and gcc seek to process?  From what I can tell, they regard situations where they view the standard as needlessly restricting optimizations as defects in the Standard, and makes no attempt to uphold the Standard as written, but I'm unaware of any document that describes all the cases where they do that.  Most situations where I've seen optimizations prove problematic are a result of compiler writers willfully ignoring the Committee intentions as documented in the Rationale.