# Lock-free list/map read-only access

Tags: c++, multithreading

My use-case:

There's a "primary" thread that does several things, among them is modification of several data structures. This is considered a "critical path", the time is very important, and delay of order of 100 nanoseconds is considerable.

There's another thread that is used to collect general info and statistics (a sort of a telemetry). Both threads run in the same process, and can access the same memory.

So, in essence, it's a problem of 1 high-priority writer, and 1 low-priority reader.

We don't want to use locks (i.e. mutex or a spinlock) to protect the data structures from modifications while they're being read.
We also can tolerate some inaccuracies, i.e. reading several variables in a non-atomic way, and sometime present "mixes" results (actually we can notice such things, and just retry telemetry collection from the beginning if this happens).
But, of course, we can't tolerate things such as accessing invalid memory. Hence iterating through a complex data structure, such as a linked list or a map (binary tree), is problematic.

So, I thought about the following strategy. The writer modifies (in an atomic way) some global flag (doesn't care if there's a reader in the middle) for the duration of the update. The reader each time checks this flag during the iteration, and in case of a collision the whole operation is aborted, and then retried.
In addition to this, during the iteration the reader each time saves its currently being-accessed pointer. So that if the writer interrupts it, and modifies the data structures, it won't immediately delete this specific pointer.

Hence, instead of this global flag, I use a pointer to the "staged" node. Once the reader staged a pointer to a `Node`, it's guaranteed to remain accessible, even if the reader is kicked-out later.

**EDIT:**
Lots of thanks to @Vincent Saulue-Laborde for noticing the problem in the initial implementation. The following is a fixed pseudo-code:

```
// Data structures
struct Node
    :public boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<>
{
    // ...
};    

typedef boost::intrusive::list<Node> List;
List m_List;

// The following is for synchronized read/write access, as described above
Node* m_pStage = nullptr;
uint64_t m_Revision = 0;

struct Writer
{
    State& m_State;
    Node* m_pStagePrev;

    Writer(State& s) :m_State(s)
    {
        // grab the ownership
        m_pStagePrev = (Node*) this;
        atomic_xchg(&m_pStage, &m_pStagePrev);
    }

    ~Writer()
    {
        m_Revision++;
        MemoryBarrier();
        
        m_pStage = m_pStagePrev; // release
        MemoryBarrier();
    }

    void DeleteNode(Node* p)
    {
        if (m_pStagePrev == p)
            // this is the situation, where we can't immediately delete it.
            m_pStagePrev = nullptr;
        else
            delete p;
    }
};

// The primary thread does the update
Writer wr(*this);

// ...
// eventually decide to delete a node from the list
Node* pNode = /* ... */;
m_List.erase(List::s_iterator_to(*pNode));
wr.DeleteNode(pNode);
// ...


// The following is used by the reader

struct Reader
{
    State* m_pState;
    Node* m_pCurrent;
    uint64_t m_Revision;

    Reader(State& s)
        :m_pState(&s)
        ,m_pCurrent(nullptr)
    {
        m_Revision = s.m_Revision;
        LockNode((Node*) this);
    }

    ~Reader()
    {
        if (m_pState)
            Detach();
    }

    bool LockNode(Node* p)
    {
        if (m_pState)
        {
            if (TryXchg(p) == m_pCurrent)
            {
                m_pCurrent = p;
                
                if (m_pState->m_Revision == m_Revision)
                    return true;
            }

            Detach(); // kicked-out
        }

        return false;
    }

private:


    Node* TryXchg(Node* p)
    {
        return atomic_cmp_xchg(&m_pState->m_pStage, m_pCurrent, p);
    }

    void Detach()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Node* p = TryXchg(nullptr);
            if (p == m_pCurrent)
                break;

            if (p == nullptr)
            {
                delete m_pCurrent; // deferred deletion, do it now
                break;
            }
            
            YieldProcessor();
        }
        
        m_pState = nullptr;
    }
};

// Reader collects the data
Reader r(*this);

for (List::iterator it = m_List.begin(); m_List.end() != it; it++)
{
    Node& node = *it;
    if (!r.LockNode(&node))
        return false;

    // safe to access the node now
    // ...
}

return true; // survived till the end - iteration complete.
```

This seems a sane design to me. The writer never waits. It only pays a single interlocked operation in the prolog, and a memory barrier in the epilog.
In addition sometimes a `Node` deletion can be deferred for an indefinite time, but only a single `Node` can be deferred.

Note: I assume that iteration step over a linked list, i.e. incrementing an iterator, is a trivial operation, that only relies on the currently locked `Node` (that's why I use `boost::intrusive::list` in this example).

Iteration step over a `map` (also `set`, `multiset`) is not such a trivial operation, can result in walking over several nodes, and hence can't be used as-is. But with some effort, by using custom data structures, the same idea can be used too. It's just the `Reader::LockNode` should be used for each micro-step.

Is this design safe? Is there a better alternative?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this.

Comment: *We also can tolerate some inaccuracies, i.e. reading several variables in a non-atomic way*  Can you tolerate accessing an invalid pointer that causes a SEGV when you dereference it?  I see nothing in the posted code that guarantees you don't read a pointer value that's corrupted because it's in the midst of being updated by another thread.  Note that not having observed it to fail (yet!) is not the same thing as working properly.

Comment: The neverending quest for a lock-free unicorn fairy almost always ends in tears.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: as I mentioned, I cold tolerate "undefined results", but not "undefined behavior", i.e. SEGV + friends.

If you see nothing in the posted code the guarantees the safety, then I can elaborate. Should I?

Comment: @valdo You can "tolerate" a `SIGSEGV` that crashes your entire process that - in your own words - "is considered a "critical path", the time is very important, and delay of order of 100 nanoseconds is considerable"?  You code makes all sorts of unwarranted assumptions about what's safe - read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63233180/is-assigning-a-pointer-in-c-program-considered-atomic-on-x86-64/63234159#63234159 for just some of the things your code ignores.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: don't mean to be pedantic, but I never said that. My "own words" are regarding mixed results, not crashes.

Comment: P.S. And, of course, I don't make "unwarranted assumptions" on what's atomic. The only atomic operations I assumed are those `atomic_xchg` and `atomic_cmp_xchg`

Comment: @valdo *... I never said that* Read your own question: "This is considered a "critical path", the time is very important, and delay of order of 100 nanoseconds is considerable."

Comment: Again, I **never** said I'm ok with crashes. I even mentioned that explicitly. Please re-read.

Comment: @valdo Well, if you're not OK with crashes you better get rid of the undefined behavior your code invokes by assuming accesses to `m_pDeferredDelete` are all of correctly ordered, visible, and atomic.  What was that someone posted earlier about "lock-free unicorn fairies"?

Comment: @valdo There are absolutely zero guarantees that the `DeleteNode()` method can not be called by a different thread.  Are your standards such that you really feel that allowing a race condition that obvious in your code is OK?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: as I mentioned, there's exactly 1 writer, and 1 reader. Period.
As you can see, `DeleteNode()` (as well as all other modifications) is only called by the writer.

Comment: If the contains UB, there's no guarantee against random crash. Reciprocal: If the code needs guarantees against random crash, there should be no UB. So you cannot tolerate wrong results of any kind in your code. Proper use of `std::atomic` can minimize the cost of synchronization, but it still imposes some runtime overhead.

Comment: @Red.Wave: Of course there should be no UB, no question here. But there's a difference between undefined behavior and undefined result.

For instance, reading uninitialized `int` is undefined result, not undefined behavior.

What I meant is that I *could* tolerate inconsistent results, i.e. read messy data which is only partially updated.
But anyway, with the solution I proposed, this should not happen.

Comment: Uninitialized variable is UB. And UB has a transitivity/propagation nature. Assume using such an unitialized integer to index an array: there's a possibility for seg_fault due to out of bounds indexing. Compilers may do aggressive On the other hand,optimizations in presence of UB, that leads to runtime surprises. UB is the tricky part of C++ programming; it has lots of sharp edges.

Comment: Your problem statement is absolutely solvable, although it's not a trivial amount of work. Neither your code nor your design however are rescuable. I'm left unsure which question you want answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this design safe?

No, it isn't. Your algorithm has **use-after-free** bugs, and can therefore segfault, corrupt your heap, in addition of having a serious security vulnerability...

Let's use simple workloads for the reader & writer threads. The reader thread access the first 2 elements of the list with a single `Reader`. The writer thread deletes the head of the list twice, with 2 different `Writer`.

This can be seen as the writer thread processing multiple queries/events/requests in a row, while the reader has been slowed/halted, for example because the OS decided to schedule another thread on the CPU at the "wrong" time.

```cpp
// Hypothesis: the list has 4 elements: [l1,l2,l3,l4].

// This hypothesis is made just to not have to make a lot of it != end() checks
// everywhere, to keep the proof simple.

void removeFirst(State& state) {
    Writer wr(state);
    auto it = m_List.begin();
    m_List.erase(it);
    wr.DeleteNode(&*it);
}

// Writer thread code
void writerThread(State& state) {
    /* w1 */ removeFirst(state);
    /* w2 */ removeFirst(state);
}

// this function reads/writes its argument.
void doRead(Node& node);

// Reader thread code
// Note: I just unrolled the first 2 iterations of OP's reader loop.
void readerThread(State& state) {
    /* r1 */ Reader r(state);
    /* r2 */ auto it = m_List.begin();
    /* r3 */ if (!r.LockNode(&*it))
                 return;
    // safe to access the node now (according to OP)...
    /* r4 */ doRead(*it);
    /* r5 */ ++it;
    /* r6 */ if (!r.LockNode(&*it))
                 return;
    // safe to access the node now (according to OP)...
    /* r7 */ doRead(*it);
}
```

I've named statements in `writerThread` w1 and w2. `readerThread` statements are named r1 to r7. Let's be **incredibly generous** and assume each statement is executed atomically with [sequentially consistent ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Sequentially-consistent_ordering) semantics. This program does a **use-after-free** if statements are executed in the following total order:

- `r1` to `r6`
- `w1` to `w2`
- `r7`

I personally like to illustrate race conditions with a 2 columns diagram showing the 2 instruction flows side by side, with annotations describing how each statement modifies the program state. I hope the following diagram makes sense:

```cpp
//       readerThread                        |    writerThread
/* r1 */ Reader r(state);                  /*|*/
/* r2 */ auto it = m_List.begin();         /*|*/
/* r3 */ if (!r.LockNode(&*it))            /*|*/
             return;                       /*|*/
         // doesn't return.                /*|*/
         // &*it == &l1;                   /*|*/
         // m_pStage == &l1;               /*|*/
/* r4 */ doRead(*it);                      /*|*/
/* r5 */ ++it;                             /*|*/
/* r6 */ if (!r.LockNode(&*it))            /*|*/
             return;                       /*|*/
         // doesn't return.                /*|*/
         // &*it == &l2;                   /*|*/
         // m_pStage == &l2;               /*|*/
         // m_pDeferredDelete == nullptr;  /*|*/
/* w1 */                                   /*|*/ /* w1 */ removeFirst(state);
                                           /*|*/          // m_list == [l2,l3,l4]
                                           /*|*/          // free(&l1)
                                           /*|*/          // m_pStage == nullptr;
                                           /*|*/          // m_pDeferredDelete == nullptr;
/* w2 */                                   /*|*/ /* w2 */ removeFirst(state);
                                           /*|*/          // m_list == [l3,l4]
                                           /*|*/          // free(&l2)
                                           /*|*/          // m_pStage == nullptr;
                                           /*|*/          // m_pDeferredDelete == nullptr;
         // &*it == &l2                    /*|*/
         // l2 was freed by w2             /*|*/
/* r7 */ doRead(*it);                      /*|*/
         // -> use-after-free              /*|*/
```

With a different ordering (r[1-3] -> w[1-2] -> r[4-7] ), I think your program might also trigger the assert in `Writer::DeleteNode(Node*)`. If true, your program might also **leak memory** on release builds.

Comment: "The reader thread access the first 2 elements of the list with a single Reader" - sorry, but this is not how it works.

First there should always be only a SINGLE reader. Secondly, the reader is NOT ALLOWED to access more than 1 element of the list!
It only can try to lock (atomically) a single list element, and, if succeeded, can only work on it. Then, during the iteration, it tries to lock the next element, from this point it's no more allowed to access the previous element, and etc.

Comment: @valdo My proof does have only a single Reader, and it does read the 2 elements exactly as you described (lock 1st -> read 1st -> lock next -> read next). The sentence you quoted doesn't contradict your specifications in any way.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I read your post inattentionally.

But there's no problem in the scenario you describe.
After the `r6` stage completes successfully the `m_pStage` will be set to point to `l2`. Hence later during `w2` the writer thread won't deallocate the `l2`, instead its deletion will be deferred.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @valdo After `r6`, `m_pStage == &l2`. Then `w1` sets `m_pStage = nullptr` when executing the 1st Writer destructor. The 2nd Writer in `w2` sees `m_pStage == nullptr` and does delete `l2`.

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. You describe a scenario where the writer (i.e. the whole update procedure) is invoked more than once, while the reader remains suspended.

That's possible. Thanks a lot! 

I'll fix this by restoring the `m_pStage` in the d'tor (rather than setting it to `nullptr`. But if done naively, the reader may miss the writer intervention at all.

I'll think about the solution.

Comment: @valdo My intuition is that your "fixed" code will have scenarios where the Writer can leave the Reader permanently deadlocked, but I won't check your next implementation. I'll just conclude by echoing the other participants of this thread: a correct, performant lock-free doubly-linked list is an **extremely complex** piece of software. A hand-written algorithm that isn't exactly a copy/paste from one based on a peer-reviewed paper with a formal proof is almost guaranteed to be incorrect. And even with a research paper, I wouldn't have much confidence in one I implemented myself.

Comment: I do think I can fix this, but thanks anyway. You were the only one who read the code, and provide a meaningful answer.

I agree that lock-free algorithms are a complex subject, but I need this for a very specific use-case

Comment: P.S. Done. If anyhow you change your mind - please review. The writer either restores the initial value of `m_pStage`, or sets it to `nullptr` to indicate deferred deletion.
The reader will now wait for writer to finish (i.e. wait in `~Reader` in a loop). It's now also responsible for the deferred deletion.
To not miss intervention in the middle by the writer, there's a revision counter.

Answer (score 2):

Your strategy does not actually guarantee global progress; it is not [fair](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/91214/concurrency-and-fairness) to the reader which might get delayed indefinitely. You never mentioned fairness in your requirements yet I assume you do require it. As such, some sort of queuing is needed. Linux does that using a (non lock-free) [ticket lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_lock). The simplest way I see is to let the reader count its retries and if the number becomes exceedingly large, then try a pessimistic lock that actually would force the writer to wait (on a spinlock, of course). The other - much more native for the lock-free world - approach would be to keep two versions of the data: on every transaction writer atomically updates all the data, gets the old version of it, and tries to update a special `old_data` **comparing it to `NULL`**; the reader never reads anything else except the `old_data` and `NULL`s it once reading is done.

---

With that being said: I suggest forgetting the lock-free religion. Proceed with a spinlock, and waste a few dozen cycles, it still gonna be significantly less than the 100 nanoseconds you've mentioned as an upper limit on relatively modern hardware. Lock-free would fail in the most unexpected way and you would spend days if not weeks trying to understand what could potentially be a root cause. The only right way to do proper lock-free stuff is by **mathematically** proving its correctness and then spending a week or months running the lock-free code under a heavy multithreaded stress. After that (and only after that) you might assume it works.

Comment: Sorry, but you got it all wrong. Not only never I mentioned the fairness, but also explicitly defined the asymmetry: the writer is on a **critical path**, it should NOT be suspended. While the reader latency is not important.

This is exactly the reason I want a lock-free design.

Comment: @valdo, well, if you are OK with the reader being delayed for arbitrarily long, then there is a simpler design: just get rid of the reader and keep the writer. That would simply the code significantly.

Comment: You can laugh, but It's a legit design for a scenario that I described. A mission-critical thread, that gets maximum priority, with auxiliary "telemetry" of lower priority.

Comment: That is not what you mean. "Lower priority" in no way implies "can wait endlessly". Being unfair to the reader in a sense I defined is equivalent to having no priority at all assigned to it rather than the low one. Low priority implies it must progress too, but with relaxed restrictions for delays.

Comment: "Lower priority" in no way implies "can wait endlessly" - I never said that. It's you interpretation of my words. And this has nothing to do about what I need.

Let me redefine the task: The writer is allowed to wait only O(1), whereas reader can wait arbitrary long, but only in case of collision with writer. If writer is idle (i.e. doesn't modify anything) the reader should not wait.

Is this clear now?

Comment: This is clear and such a definition is theoretically unsolvable.