# AVX512 Gather/Scatter atomicity/aliasing

Tags: c++, vectorization, simd, avx, avx512

I'm trying to vectorize the following program:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    a = arr[i];
    //arithmetic on *a* here.
    count[a]++;
}
```

Using intrinsics this becomes something like:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i+=8)
{
    __m512i a = _mm512_loadu_epi64(arr+i);
    //arithmetic on *a* here.
    __m512i gather_a = _mm512_i64gather_epi64(a,cnt,8);
    int64_t val1 = 1;
    temp = _mm_cvtsi64_si128(val1);
    __m512i one   = _mm512_broadcastq_epi64(temp);
    __m512i added  = _mm512_add_epi64(gather_a, one); //count[a]++;
    _mm512_i64scatter_epi64(count,a,added,8);
}
```

The problem is that the vectorized version's results in the output *count* array seems to be slightly off here and there. Is this problem related to the atomicity of AVX gather/scatter intrinsics or is this some other problem related to aliasing on the array?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check for conflicts between indices? `vpconflictq` exists for that purpose.  If that's possible, it's not a problem of [per-element atomicity for scatter stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012574/per-element-atomicity-of-vector-load-store-and-gather-scatter), it's that vector gather / vector increment / vector scatter isn't the same as incrementing one element at a time.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `_mm_cvtsi64_si128(1)` and so on; the normal way to write broadcast constants is `__m512i one = _mm512_set1_epi64( 1 );`.

Comment: I guess you could call conflicts (same bucket twice in the vector) a form of aliasing, so yes, aliasing.