# How to force gcc to use avx2 for copying a 32-byte struct with shared between threads?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, avx, avx2

Consider the following example compiled with `-O3 -march=native`:

```
struct str{
    volatile uint64_t a1;
    volatile uint64_t a2;
    volatile uint64_t a3;
    volatile uint64_t a4;
};

int main(void){
    struct str str1;
    struct str str2;
    str1.a1 = str2.a2;
    str1.a2 = str2.a2;
    str1.a3 = str2.a3;
    str1.a4 = str2.a4;
}
```

It produce the following assembly code:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        vpxor   xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        vmovdqu8        YMMWORD PTR [rsp-32], ymm0
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp-24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-64], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp-24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-56], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp-16]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-48], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp-8]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-40], rax
        xor     eax, eax
        vzeroupper
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

[**godbolt live example**](https://godbolt.org/z/cYM43WMoz)

On my machine `KbL i7-8550U` it produces pretty much the same machine code:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   pxor   xmm0,xmm0
   movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp-0x28],xmm0
   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp-0x20]
   movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp-0x18],xmm0
   mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x48],rax
   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp-0x20]
   mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x40],rax
   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp-0x18]
   mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x38],rax
   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp-0x10]
   mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x30],rax
   xor    eax,eax
   ret
```

On my machine there's a support for `avx2`, but no `SIMD` is used for copying.

How to hint `gcc` to use `256 bit` based `SIMD` (since the structure has 256 bytes in size)?

Comment: Don't use `volatile`.  GCC will do each `volatile` access with a separate access, not as an element of a SIMD vector.  If those were MMIO addresses, that's necessary for correctness.

Comment: @PeterCordes I used volatile to prevent the entire store/load to be optimized away since the struct is supposed to be shared across different threads. x86 memory ordering rules in turns guarantee correct memory ordering.

Comment: Compilers don't optimize `volatile`. If you remove that, you will get [good code](https://godbolt.org/z/Gcv5zqv8q). Also, you copy `a2` to `a1`. I assume that's a typo.

Comment: `volatile` does *not* guarantee correct memory ordering because it doesn't prevent compile-time reordering (unless you're using MSVC with `/volatile:ms`).  Use `_Atomic` with `memory_order_release` for stores, `memory_order_acquire` for loads, if that's what you want.

Comment: @PeterCordes `volatile` does not, but it guarantees that the stores and loads to the volatile variable would be made as with a rule of the abstract machine. x86 memory model guarantees that stores are no reordered with early loads.

Comment: @PeterCordes `_Atomic`s are not lock-free in case of copying data larger than 8 bytes on `x86`

Comment: For testing how something compiles, write a function that takes pointers, or acts on globals, as discussed in *[How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)*.  See https://godbolt.org/z/5h9Gc9o9c : GCC `-march=skylake` uses AVX2 for your shuffle as written, or to straight copy if you don't duplicate `a2`.

Comment: Unfortunately, GCC doesn't make any assumptions about [Per-element atomicity of vector load/store and gather/scatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46012574) so `_Atomic uint64_t` members result in per-element copying, and I don't know a good way around that. https://godbolt.org/z/8zGE4soMe . If the struct was aligned by 16, it would be 100% safe and guaranteed on paper to copy it as two 128-bit halves with `movaps`, on CPUs with AVX (at least Intel), since Intel finally got around to documenting that AVX implies 128-bit load/store atomicity for aligned accesses.

Comment: Consider aligning your struct by 32 bytes (`_Alignas(32)` on the first member), and using `volatile __m256i*` to copy it.  The whole struct copy will be atomic in practice on modern CPUs. https://rigtorp.se/isatomic/.  And I don't know of any that will tear within 8-byte chunks, which is all you're getting from GCC's interpretation of `volatile` as giving tear-free accesses up to integer register width, suitable for how the Linux kernel uses it for atomics. (See [comments on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71867102/224132) for GCC avoiding a non-atomic store for volatile on AArch64.)

Comment: @PeterCordes `__mm256i` load/stores accepts only non-`volatile` pointers. The way I see to resolve the problem is to use `volatile union { struct str str, __m256i raw_memory }`. But then `_mm256_load_si256` would required explicit cast to discard volatile from the pointer. How safe that might be?

Comment: I think you're talking about intrinsics like `_mm256_load_si256`?  I meant to deref the `volatile __m256i*` pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC will do each `volatile` access with a separate access in asm, not as an element of a SIMD vector. If those were MMIO addresses, that's necessary for correctness.  **By using `volatile`, you're forbidding GCC from doing the optimization you want!**

For testing how something compiles, write a function that takes pointers, or acts on globals, as discussed in *[How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)*. See https://godbolt.org/z/5h9Gc9o9c : without `volatile`, GCC and clang `-march=skylake` use AVX2 for your shuffle as written, or to straight copy with 256-bit load/store if you don't duplicate `a2`.

---

> I used volatile to prevent the entire store/load to be optimized away since the struct is supposed to be shared across different threads.

If you're going to use `volatile` on each `uint64_t` separately, you could have just used `_Atomic` (with `memory_order_relaxed` or `release`.)

> x86 memory ordering rules in turns guarantee correct memory ordering.

You can't count on ordering that because `volatile` doesn't do anything to prevent reordering at *compile* time, except of volatile accesses with respect to other `volatile`s, so you won't get guaranteed acquire/release synchronization.  It's a lot like `memory_order_relaxed`.

`_Atomic uint64_t` with `memory_order_acquire`/`release` would give you the same code-gen as `volatile` but with guaranteed behaviour.   *[When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118)* - pretty much never, unless you can't get `_Atomic` / `std::atomic<>` to make good asm, like in this case where neither it nor `volatile uint64_t` will do exactly what you want.

```
struct str{
// _Alignas(32)    // probably a good idea
  _Atomic uint64_t a1;  // or atomic_uint_least64_t, or volatile
  _Atomic uint64_t a2;
  _Atomic uint64_t a3;
  _Atomic uint64_t a4;
};

// I don't really recommend this; it ignores the _Atomic qualifier on members
void copy2(volatile struct str *str1, volatile const struct str *str2) {
    *str1 = *str2;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyagA%2BudTkVjVEQJDqzTAGF09AK5smBpwBkCTNgAcp4ARtikILIADuhKxPZMrh5eBrHxdkL%2BgSFs4ZGy1ti2iSJELKREyZ7ePFbYNplMZRVE2cFhEVFW5ZXVqXVKvW0BHXld0gCUVujupKicXACkAEwAzAGoHjgA1EtrzgFERACe0dhKAHRI%2B7hLWgCCqxtMW%2B67%2B85DmCwkbASoa63e5PR6nc44Gg7aG/dD/VCmdxHUyMFhDABs0lMRB2ABV9gAhEEAemJ4OwkJ2ADc3L8GNgdkjhJjsXjCSChqR3LYdpylgB2ImPaHQ0wPegEYCsJQQNYrSYg6G4nYsHjs4V4lUrdUPJUqtY6vUsaQ6gUAEVNj1JOxOs1IOzIkoCEh2GBwIJpBEwvKQ7hoNEYEE53JxnJ2ACpOXVXUIhryiFyeWHIwn5XtBYqRVGALS3VV7NZm%2BOkFa5ta4FjatYE6HWzDuaIS8REBmVzPQnN5lYFouc0tdwm14kqpje9wqHZEJAMyEsdz0UPYACOplQcZIPvQAHcdupUEhgPGyBcdrR5/QdqEKqQCBEFRqOwmeGWK2se8X%2B%2BWWAbq%2B3i8%2B82kd8%2BxfY1TX5C0rXDD10C9GNohOIMExDYsIyjcgYyYONgyTBM0NTSZ0yFXURVheFTCGY9TGwdRGwBYgIFWdFOy/aMQLzaMODYMgTlMMgcFIUxSAaFh1ApBVfwfFU/gBCiSGE6jaKbBimJYisVgw9ivw0nYuJ4vjSAEoSRLEzAJOIkVpLhWTKIUmi6NQFSVmYp9QLWTTUzcjC9NIXj%2BIiYyjFM8y/zImz5OwRSHKclzSAAr9ZA/UDEp8vzDIC4TURUELHnNEFw2JGC4IwBCVggGkjDsRhixQ5N0OpWkqoZDAsNDZDcPtFMS0IgULJFLqeHfLqqxrHZrVCdwcXEJhLwZdBojsf4AC8KRVLcWBOS4QXNLhpnobgAFZ%2BG8LgdHIdBuGcXk7QWPZ1j4cgiG0XbpgAaxAFYDsMbhpGO57zu4fglBALRHue6Y4FgFAMDYaJ6QoKgIBhuHGEiVBgB4OVyBwKkAWwAA1W8twAeXOE6HroBcImBiBQn%2B0JnV87gHoZ1hfOJ0JdGKJ7eH4GGOGEYmmHoE5/pwCbgGcCR6GB3nsewNhjGASRTv4QhhJKKkLn%2BmjikmxYHqOBp/olUJSAqE5XBwZn%2BATAg2Bt6YAxYYAlEJ7ASbJm25GEMQJE4GQfcUFQNH%2B/Q6iMEwQHMVdDAIUJgcgaZ5qaWXs2Jt9s0V%2BYbkLJRXpOIxXoZbMAHVpf4dAtdIG8cETiBpiKEoHAgJx%2Blqcg/FGXJ8jSOIEiEdu%2B4yRJ2h7rpBgabnSmGIfJ8aGfWjHzpIkGWe3BqAwhiX7uV6kRuboDvbDr%2B1WAa4XcAA50WzTEdmAVBUB2THLm7CB8GIMg7rWHhJlt8G3ofS%2BvtLgv1yAnTOhdLgQMQZg1VhDRAEBoZwhRhESg1BkbwzQFsJWPB%2BRaDqDjPG7tPbMG9pTFspAaZ0zPqzC23s6Hs05tzb2/NmBECFiLMW2AJZS3oDLb2OBFYmBVmddW08tayzOrrVA%2BtvZGxAWdU25tfJWwNrbG8DteZOyMK7EhpMyFy0EL7cQkhA7GODmoTQZ99AaUjmYCwccE7wGTgtRIacM47CzhUfc%2BwzT50LiwYuXjy78J2JXautdtZJ3qAvFubcN4DE7qOZe4xV7kHSAPJIiSO6ZKaKk3u89p5CBaH0HJW8p7N2aMMApE8eitDnvUyotTV4HzmAsfe30uBHXAf9KBV8b53xwSYZ%2B/JLhaEuINd%2BhB5Lf1/v/eBgCVjSEuAATnWRszZmz0RdLARAyugMrCwJ5joBB8AkEgFmEQaIk10FIxQfDII7BFjqGvrfICwzDx4PGZM/gFJP61wMBYv2ZjZAWOUFYsOH1yBbnNtER2XSen7PPsTSaNycToChK8wZHz7GjJ%2BVM1wsN4bf3lAs05SzgE/VPpAw5wNQYnJel0lY/AHb4MuPyH%2B%2BDOV4K0Dy/kvSz5QPJbtcgkNkCXLRbcxG/z5JeiBfIEFAcwXyAhaHGxBhYUsHhdoxFNKDlcFRdcyaDosVvLvg/J%2BL835EtQfaZ48y4EUvINOFgAlqDH1Aayj6qzX7okvisVZzkA1Bv9WsWQyLhVHIZQArpax9XnxFZMaY1d4gOGkEAA%3D%3D)

```
# GCC13 and Clang 17 both make the same asm  -O3 -march=skylake
copy2:
        vmovdqu ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi]
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rdi], ymm0
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

But beware this won't work in C++; struct assignment turns into a per-element copy and `std::atomic<>`'s copy-constructor is deleted.  Or with `volatile`, the implicit copy-constructor isn't marked `volatile` so won't copy a struct with `volatile` members.

Unfortunately, GCC and Clang don't make any assumptions about *[Per-element atomicity of vector load/store and gather/scatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012574/per-element-atomicity-of-vector-load-store-and-gather-scatter)* so `_Atomic uint64_t` members result in per-element copying, and I don't know a great way around that without some hacky code. https://godbolt.org/z/8zGE4soMe .  (And they don't optimize atomics anyway; the compiler internals probably treat atomics a lot like `volatile`, since that's one way to make sure they aren't optimized away.)

If the struct was aligned by 16, it would be 100% safe and guaranteed on paper to copy it as two 128-bit halves with `movaps` or `vmovdqa`, on CPUs with AVX (at least Intel), since Intel finally got around to documenting that **AVX implies 128-bit load/store atomicity for aligned accesses**.  *[SSE instructions: which CPUs can do atomic 16B memory operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646018/sse-instructions-which-cpus-can-do-atomic-16b-memory-operations/7647825#7647825)*

---

#### A real-world hack to get the asm you want, fairly safe / future-proof

Consider aligning your struct by 32 bytes (`_Alignas(32)` on the first member), and using `volatile __m256i*` to copy it.  (Dereference the pointer directly, *don't* use `_mm256_load_si256`.)  This is exactly like using `volatile uint64_t*` but you're forcing the compiler to do one 32-byte access instead of four 8-byte accesses.

**The whole struct copy will be atomic in practice on modern CPUs, except for Alder Lake E-cores where each 128-bit half will be atomic. https://rigtorp.se/isatomic/.**

I don't know of any that will tear within 8-byte chunks, which is all you're getting from GCC's interpretation of `volatile` as giving tear-free accesses up to integer register width, suitable for how the Linux kernel uses it for atomics. (See [comments on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71867102/224132) for GCC avoiding a non-atomic store for volatile on AArch64.)

More importantly, there isn't a plausible mechanism for a CPU to tear within the elements of a wide SIMD store even if it breaks it up into 8-byte or 16-byte chunks to store separately.  Since it's aligned, the 8-byte partial chunks are also aligned, especially when the whole vector is naturally aligned.  On paper, accesses wider than 16 bytes (or wider than 8 without AVX) have zero guarantees so a Deathstation 9000 x86 could break such code, but accessing cache more than once for the same 8-byte chunk makes no practical sense.

Using `_mm256_loadu_si256` without alignment wouldn't work because it's not `volatile`.  (In GNU C, `volatile` is more or less well-defined and supported for rolling your own `relaxed` atomics.  And don't be tempted to use `asm("" ::: "memory")` to force a load or store to happen around non-volatile accesses: see [Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?](https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/) for some of the more obscure optimizations that can bite you, like inventing extra loads to something non-volatile the source reads once.)

Using your own `__attribute__((aligned(1),vector_size(32),may_alias))` unaligned vector to allow a `volatile*` would be a 32-byte copy with single-instruction load/store ([or 16-byte halves depending on tuning settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626726/why-doesnt-gcc-resolve-mm256-loadu-pd-as-single-vmovupd)).  But if it was only aligned by 8, on paper you have no guarantees about atomicity even within the 8-byte elements.  And in practice you could get tearing between elements.  Probably best to make it naturally aligned to it's definitely within one cache line, and not split across cache banks or whatever on some AMD CPUs.

Comment: (After comments under the question clarified the real question, I threw this together fairly quickly once I realized my comments amounted to an answer.  Edits welcome, or let me know if it seems disorganized.)