# Efficient way to reset array of structs which contain a std::atomic member?

Tags: c++, stdatomic, memset, auto-vectorization

Let's say I have a struct `Foo` s. t.

```cpp
struct alignas(64) Foo {
    std::atomic<int> value;
    Foo* other;
};
```

Then, if I have an array `Foo array[2048];` of `Foo`'s: **I already have initialized the array, but it has some dirty values inside, I want to reset it back to zero state.**

If I want to reset this array to zeroed `Foo`'s without violating standard there is an efficient way to do it in C (if `Foo` has `value` of type not `std:atomic<int>`, but `volatile int`): `memset`.

However, what is safe, yet efficient, way to do it in C++?

Comment: How about `Foo array[2048] = {};`?

Comment: I'm too afraid about the performance of that statement because of the whole `atomic` thing honestly :(

Comment: "reset" like initializing it, using it and then reset it again to zeros? Its a nitpick, but "zero initialization" is a formal term, but you can only initialize the array once

Comment: One question per post. Also zero-initializing and resetting are different things as initialization happens only once.

Comment: Also, I already have initialized array, but it has some dirty values inside, I want to reset it back to zero state

Comment: For only that few elements, there's no need for threads or anything, that will just be less effective (creating the threads will be expensive). Just let the compiler-generated "zero" or default-construction do its work.

Comment: Perhaps `std::array<Foo, 2048> array;` and then assignment like `array = {};`? Doesn't work with atomics though. For the atomic value, there's no way other than explicitly assigning the value `0` to it.

Comment: And as usual when it comes to "performance" or being "effective", you *always* need to measure, benchmark and profile an optimized build. If it's not among the top-two or -three then it's usually not a big enough deal to worry about. Good enough often is good enough. Unless you have some very strict requirements, but then the design should have accounted for that.

Comment: When you **profiled** your code, how was `for(size_t i = 0; i < 2048; ++i) { array[i].value = 0; array[i].other = nullptr; }`?

Comment: When given the simplest possible loop, both GCC and Clang produce simple "store 0" instructions, but clang also unrolls the loop a few times.

Comment: `std::ranges::fill(arr, Foo{});`. But if you use `std::array<Foo, 2024> arr;` instead of raw array, then just `arr={};`. You don't need any **mem** function in modern C++. They're buried down the implementation of std features.

Comment: Change your perspective from *"Cannot be done like pointers or C"* to **"How to best do it safer, yet better than C or pointers"**; Then you'll find the correct way.

Comment: Unrelated: `struct Foo*` -> `Foo*`.

Comment: So are you asking if adding the atomic variable invalidates the use of memset to reinitialize the structure?

Comment: One thing that would make it faster is not wasting 4x the space on padding.  Your struct would be 16 bytes (on a typical 64-bit architecture) without `alignas(64)`.  It can make sense to align the whole array of structs by 64, but aligning every individual struct puts each one in a separate cache line.  Perhaps you're doing that to avoid false-sharing?  That does make it slower to zero them.

Comment: `memset` works in practice on mainstream C++ implementations because `std::atomic<int>` is lock-free and its object representation is the same as an `int`.  (For larger non-lock-free atomic objects, some compilers (I think MSVC) include a mutex inside the `std::atomic` object, and you shouldn't zero it.)  On `atomic<int>`, It's not UB to change the bytes of a `std::atomic<int>` in GNU C++ because internally it's just an `int` with member functions using compiler built-ins like GNU C `__atomic_load`.

Comment: Of course this would be data-race UB if there are other threads reading or writing any array members when you zero it.  So I assume you aren't doing that.  You could use C++20 `std::atomic_ref` to do atomic ops on plain `int` variables, so your struct could be `struct Foo {  alignas (std::atomic_ref<int>::required_alignment) int value;  Foo *other; }`, making it fully 100% safe to `memset` when no other thread can be accessing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object-representation of a null pointer is not guaranteed to be the bit-pattern `0`, so even in C it's not fully portable to use `memset` instead of assignment of `ptr = 0;`.  But all modern mainstream systems use `0` as the bit-pattern for null pointers.  In the rest of this answer, I'll assume that you only care about optimizing for such platforms.

`volatile int` is also not guaranteed by standards to be thread-safe in C or C++ (although [it does work on most compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118) as a legacy way to do something like atomic with `memory_order_relaxed`).  **`memset` on a struct containing `volatile` members doesn't respect their volatility** so your proposed C equivalent was potentially not even safe in practice, let alone guaranteed by anything.  The C equivalent of `std::atomic<int>` / `std::atomic_int` is `_Atomic int` / `atomic_int`.  C11 doesn't have a portable `atomic_ref`, only compiler-specific stuff like GNU C `__atomic_load_n` etc.

---

To allow efficient zeroing during single-threaded phases of your program, consider using C++20 [`std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) on a plain `int` member of your struct instead of a `std::atomic<int>` member.  This makes your struct only have primitive types as members, making it safe to use `memset` as long as no other threads are reading or writing simultaneously.  (Or `std::fill`.)

```
struct Foo {
   alignas (std::atomic_ref<int>::required_alignment) int value;
   Foo *other;
};
```

It would still be data-race UB to `memset` a struct while any other threads could be reading or writing it, so this only helps if you have phases of your program where synchronization guarantees that no other threads will be accessing your array.  Unless you want to rely on non-portable behaviour

---

One thing that would make it faster is not padding your structs to 4x the size. Your struct would be 16 bytes (on a typical 64-bit architecture) without `alignas(64)`, or 8 bytes total with 32-bit pointers. It can make sense to align the whole array of structs by 64, but aligning every individual struct puts each one in a separate cache line. Perhaps you're doing that to avoid false-sharing? That does make it slower to zero them since it's more cache-lines to write, so test to see if (and how much) it speeds up your program on various hardware to have each pointer+counter pair in its own cache line.

With 3/4 of the space being padding (assuming 16-byte `Foo` objects), `memset` on the whole array would typically be doing at least 2 stores per struct (x86-64 with AVX2 for 32-byte stores).  Worse on AArch64 without SVE (16-byte vectors), much worse on RISC-V32 without vector extensions (just 4-byte scalar stores, AFAIK).

**So if you are going to use this much padding, it's not bad to just loop manually and do normal assignments to the two members of each struct.**  If this has to be thread-safe (so you can't just access a plain `int`), use `memory_order_relaxed` for the atomic member, unless you need something stronger.  You certainly don't want to be draining the store buffer for every struct, which is what would happen on x86 with `arr[i].value = 0;` (which defaults to `seq_cst`), so use `arr[i].value.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed)`.

Looping manually would result in two stores per struct when you really only need one 16-byte store.  Compilers don't optimize atomics, and they won't turn `.value.store(0, relaxed); .other = nullptr;` into a single 16-byte store, unfortunately.  Even without an `atomic` member, GCC has a missed-optimization ([bug 82142](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82142)) where it avoids writing padding, stopping it from coalescing stores when doing struct assignment.  Using `size_t value` or `ptrdiff_t value` could avoid that.

With no atomic members, store coalescing should result in a loop that does one 16-byte store (or 8-byte in 32-bit code) per 64-byte struct.  Unfortunately GCC fails at that for x86-64, but clang succeeds.  GCC gets it right for AArch64.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <stddef.h>

struct alignas(64) Foo_atomic_ref {
   alignas (std::atomic_ref<ptrdiff_t>::required_alignment) ptrdiff_t value;  // pointer sized to avoid padding between members which trips up GCC's store coalescing.
   Foo_atomic_ref *other;
};

Foo_atomic_ref shared_array_aref[1024];

// if no other threads could be accessing the array
void zero_array_nonatomic(){
    for (auto &s : shared_array_aref){
        s.value = 0;     // GCC for x86-64 fails to use movdqa; AArch64 uses stp though.
        s.other = nullptr;
    }
}

// if some other threads could be accessing the array
void zero_array_atomic_ref(){
    for (auto &s : shared_array_aref){
        std::atomic_ref ref(s.value);  // free to construct
        ref.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        s.other = nullptr;             // separate stores from both compilers
    }
}
```

**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:78,endLineNumber:22,positionColumn:78,positionLineNumber:22,selectionStartColumn:78,selectionStartLineNumber:22,startColumn:78,startLineNumber:22),source:%27%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstddef.h%3E%0A%0Astruct+alignas(64)+Foo_atomic_ref+%7B%0A+++alignas+(std::atomic_ref%3Cptrdiff_t%3E::required_alignment)+ptrdiff_t+value%3B++//+pointer+sized+to+avoid+padding+between+members+which+trips+up+GCC!%27s+store+coalescing.%0A+++Foo_atomic_ref+*other%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AFoo_atomic_ref+shared_array_aref%5B1024%5D%3B%0A%0Avoid+zero_array_nonatomic()%7B%0A++++for+(auto+%26s+:+shared_array_aref)%7B%0A++++++++s.value+%3D+0%3B+++++//+GCC+for+x86-64+fails+to+use+movdqa%3B+AArch64+uses+stp+though.%0A++++++++s.other+%3D+nullptr%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+zero_array_atomic_ref()%7B%0A++++for+(auto+%26s+:+shared_array_aref)%7B%0A++++++++std::atomic_ref+ref(s.value)%3B++//+free+to+construct%0A++++++++ref.store(0,+std::memory_order_relaxed)%3B%0A++++++++s.other+%3D+nullptr%3B+++++++++++++//+separate+stores+from+both+compilers%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Astruct+alignas(64)+Foo_atomic+%7B%0A+++std::atomic%3Cint%3E+value%3B%0A+++Foo_atomic+*other%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.996973627323825,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g1320,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20+-mcpu%3Dcortex-a77%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+ARM64+gcc+13.2.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:64.74808963874622,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1701,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:45,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:45,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:45,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:45,startLineNumber:10),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:64.74808963874622,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+ARM64+gcc+13.2.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:35.25191036125379,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:61.00302637267618,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)** - GCC for x86-64 fails to coalesce the two 8-byte stores even in the non-atomic version where that would be possible.  But GCC for AArch64 does use scalar `stp  xzr, xzr, [x0]` for it, which is also a 16-byte store of the zero-register twice.  Most microarchitectures run it as a single 16-byte store, at least on ARMv8.4 and later where it's guaranteed atomic.  So it's efficient

Clang compiles these to asm at least as good as memset, with unrolled loops without any branching to handle tiny sizes, just an unrolled loop.  The nonatomic version only does one `movaps  xmmword ptr [rax], xmm0` per struct; the `atomic_ref` loop does separate stores for each member.  Neither spend instructions storing the padding like `memset` on the whole array would do.

```
# clang -O3 
zero_array_atomic_ref():
        lea     rax, [rip + shared_array_aref]
        lea     rcx, [rip + shared_array_aref+65536]
.LBB1_1:
        mov     qword ptr [rax], 0
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 8], 0        # first struct
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 64], 0
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 72], 0       # second struct
    ....
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 448], 0
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 456], 0
        add     rax, 512
        cmp     rax, rcx
        jne     .LBB1_1
        ret
```

On real hardware, the `atomic_ref` version would also be safe with 16-byte `movaps` stores, but hardware vendors don't guarantee it.  See [Per-element atomicity of vector load/store and gather/scatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012574/per-element-atomicity-of-vector-load-store-and-gather-scatter) - it's not plausible that a 16-byte aligned store could have tearing at 8-byte boundaries on x86, especially since 8-byte atomicity is guaranteed.

On x86 with AVX, 16-byte stores are guaranteed atomic, so it would actually be fully safe for GCC and clang to coalesce the atomic 8-byte store to `.value` with the non-atomic 8-byte store to `.other`.  But compilers aren't that smart, treating `atomic` a lot like `volatile`.

It's frustrating to know that most (all?) hardware can do stuff C++ won't let you do portably, but such is life in writing portable programs.

You could manually vectorize with SIMD intrinsics like `_mm_store_si128`.  Or modern compilers will inline a 16-byte `memset` as a single instruction, but there's no guarantee of that.  Or use `offsetof(Foo, other) + sizeof(Foo::other)` as the size for each `memset`, to only write the parts of struct that contain the non-padding data.  [`offsetof` isn't guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) on structs that aren't "standard layout", but C++17 makes that "conditionally supported" instead of UB.  But of course `memset` on objects being read+written by other threads is data-race UB so I don't recommend that unless you want to carefully check your code for every compiler version, and any change to where this zeroing gets inlined into, to make sure it always compiles to safe asm.

(`std::fill` wouldn't be usable this way since it takes an iterator range of the same type.  You can't pass it a `ptrdiff_t *` as the start and a `Foo **` as the end iterators.  You could pass it a whole `Foo *`, but then might do a 64-byte struct assignment, unless the compiler decided to skip storing the padding.  If you care a lot about what asm you're getting, it's probably not a good choice.)

---

#### With `std::atomic<int>`, not plain `int` + `atomic_ref`

In this case, `std::fill` won't compile because `std::atomic` is not trivially-copyable (deleted copy-constructor).  In C++, struct assignment goes per-member.  `memset` will bypass that and let you do things you're not "supposed" to do.

If no other threads are running, `memset` on a `std::atomic<int>` (or a struct containing one) works in practice on mainstream C++ implementations because `std::atomic<int>` is lock-free and its object representation is the same as an `int`.  But I wouldn't recommend writing code this way since ISO C++ doesn't guarantee it.

On GCC/Clang and libstdc++ or libc++, `std::atomic<int>` will have a plain `int` member, and the member functions are wrappers for compiler built-ins like GNU C `__atomic_load_n` and `__atomic_fetch_add`.   So there'd be no UB in using `memset` to change the bytes of the object representation.  But again, ISO C++ doesn't guarantee anything about the internals of `std::atomic` so this would be relying on implementation details.

For larger non-lock-free atomic objects like `atomic<big_struct>`, some compilers (like MSVC: [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyahUAUgBMAIUtXyKxqiIEh1ZpgDC6egFc2TA3cAGQImbAA5PwAjbFIpADZyAAd0JWIXJi9ffwMUtOchELDIthi4nkSHbCcMkSIWUiIsvwCee2xHAqY6hqIiiOjYhPt6xuactqVRvtCB0qGKgEp7dB9SVE4uSwBmUNRfHDNtj1QpwmEj3DMtAEEdvYPsI48WEjYCc22r2%2BubqdIfE4ANRpdREbDMIFmADsNluQIRQNCRG2FgA%2BkQgQ1SGYAKxWaR4gAiRzhN0RQIA9JSgQBxDweIGCUhA9QADniAFp4tIgZh0NglEwwFxMWFsJggfR0KgANahYBYzESehMshAiqcqIAT3BIKIAKcSl%2BFOpQKsPkx9I80KxTElRnBLPE9HoSiBaLRr3Q71QaOlLElNFIPqlBCi3t9IPQSMx4iYfIISiSr1QSCBJCBPhUUplsqBqDYSXUaeAFSsQPVLETNBosWYmP%2Br2wwG15DDsuwQNI1Qb9G1QJuADUABrtgg0LEANxYDBYUUYADoTYizSou0giEQkkoQNTgKhUIvgEwfIuyMBKYxgCxUNrOWx6JSD6hOSmiGnBZSLFoeNDOb%2BlJsEowBaBY2zSNIi6bo%2BvwwiS2xkr8yIggQABe2AQIsMIVj2RBrAmaQYegNAQGcIAgJGHzPKC4LMJc2GIVC0Ikj8ty0RCCaCOgZFEJgFFUZ8HgcfRXxYoszFkhSeEEVii4BpgWGknBLG/Fwyz0NwuL8AEXA6OQ6DcB4ti2NGawbFC4F8OQRDaOpyyyiAkGLvEbJaNIuK4ts0IAJzQl5fmGNw0j8GwIC4lo5C6fphlcPwu6RbZenqeQcCwCgGBFgwsSUNQmVJNlcTAJ5kV0PQTq7hAUR2eQUShA02rcNZdWsKQ2oAPJRLo1RJdZmUcMI7VMP2NU4FEPjAC8rq7rw/A4GwxjAJIyXkIQPY1FOgo1dg6jVJamzWciHQ1fQ4akA1Xg4DVBoEGFs3LDQRjAEoQ4ENgADu7VJMwTX8IIwhiBInAyHIwjKGomgrfoFiGItaAmdYhjhrukDLOgSRdDNnLtRYQIPg0aZHESSAsEo70dKqnJnETJ4%2BAjVg8NZ6CbaQpAEDgKNYe0nQZG49rjK05DBLMJRlLkqTpEIAvi/kGT9KLCzcz1tTTNLkwdMrQg9I08uDOUIy9GrBs6yLetSMsSirOswMaVpOk1bFrIctyvIvkCuKLriQIQPgxDqjsPCLPwSU6IsyxINggZDFzmlcCF5BhRFUUO9w8UgIldlh%2BQjnOa57med5fkBdCQVcNs9srbFweZ6liAQBlPoFYwFBUBA%2BWFSAU6oEkSRolOPA%2BWi3louoPICAwFXUNVK0tQ1v21fVbWdd1Tjz/1DZDSNK1jRNU1uvP82Lct%2Blrcrm0zfpO17eC89HbH%2BmnVE51tZdmz6Tdd18A9T0vW9n3fbpay/1RAumBrIYB4MNA1X0G0IwJh4bWFsEjKInM0YYwyFjHG/BmaxDZhzeAFsNY1FcBAdwRthbFDNm0PIktMjeBaDLWhut5j6yqMQ7oqt6ETCVuw7WMxKEsIMFMQ2XDBbCJNgIsWgcVjmRtqXbSydK7cFZDyIEwEu5An7j5Rc3lva%2BxICyAOQcbKZwciACw0IXK4j8tCKyv5wK/hLrHeO0VsGp3sOnExyVlhpWQGgRuhVcptwCc3Tu3de5aLRDIEeY8yqTyqjVWebV55JI6l1Hqa8fQDSIJvRq29sDjUmiqGa1lD4mGPnNAg61nDn22rtVA%2B1b7CGOitR%2Bz9tSv2umzT%2BKVHosGeq9D6X0fqzVBiAoGUhwHyEgZDfS%2Bhtiw3geYRBiNH6oIMugoQmCLDYJZngraqMeFdD5p4URgR7TMKkckCWXQjY0K6JcxWbCuh8KNs8lWvRHmsM4dkMR0wvnmxkdbQFscFGuIMso0evJ1GoE0QPRcMg9GEAMZZbYgdq7ePDpHHAcQuaOQsVYmxdieAOL/KXFxKc4oeIzpi0uOzFExXcSHey5AWZpFcNIIAA%3D%3D%3D)) include a spinlock inside the `std::atomic` object.  IDK if any compilers include a full `std::mutex` which shouldn't be zeroed even if you know it's unlocked (no concurrent readers or writers).  (Most other compilers [use a separate hash table of spinlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298358/where-is-the-lock-for-a-stdatomic), and people have said MSVC is planning that change for their next C++ ABI break.)

MSVC uses zero as the unlocked state so static zero-initialized storage is usable directly, but in theory an implementation could have 0 meaning locked, so memset would create a deadlock.
Zeroing a spinlock while there are concurrent readers or writers could let some threads see torn values and maybe cause some memory_order weirdness.

---

It's still data-race UB to `memset` while other threads might be reading or writing the object.  In practice it will probably just work since any decent `memset` will work internally as if storing in chunks at least as wide as `int`, especially on a large aligned array, and in asm a `relaxed` atomic store doesn't need any special instructions on mainstream platforms.

But without actual guarantees, there's a lot of "this *probably* won't break" being relied on, so I wouldn't recommend it for portable code.  Only consider `memset` while other threads are running if you need to squeeze every drop of performance out of something for a specific compiler / standard library and architecture, and are prepared to verify your assumptions by checking the asm of the standard library implementation, or checking what gets inlined into your code.

And as I said earlier, padding your structs to one per cache line means only 1/4 or 1/8th of the bytes actually need to get stored, so an optimized libc `memset` isn't such an advantage.  If you only aligned your structs by their size, `memset` could be a lot better since it's able to use 32-byte stores even if the rest of your program isn't compiled to depend on x86 AVX or ARM SVE or whatever.

On some microarchitectures, storing every byte of a cache line could have advantages in allowing the CPU to just invalidate other copies of the cache line without doing a Read For Ownership.  Normally a store needs to merge some bytes into the old value of a cache line, but storing every byte of it can avoid that.  But a CPU would have to detect that across multiple stores, not just looking at the first store to a line, unless you're using AVX-512 to store a whole cache line at once.  (And even then IDK if x86 CPUs do anything special for aligned `vmovdqa64 [mem], zmm`, but they might.)  See also [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy) for more about no-RFO store protocols on x86 CPUs.  It's normally most relevant for larger arrays that don't fit in cache, but could be relevant here.  NT stores like `movntps` / `_mm_stream_ps` also avoid RFOs, but they fully evict from cache, including from L3, so that makes the next read slower.  (Shared L3 cache is normally a backstop for coherency traffic.)

Comment: I read it all even though I didn't need to know all those details cause your writing feels like a sweet novel! With that aside, "*some compilers (I think MSVC) include a mutex inside the std::atomic object*" Is there any reason for them to not use a binary semaphores instead of a mutex? Aren't binary semaphores faster?

Comment: @digito_evo: Oh, I forgot if it was a full `std::mutex` or just a spinlock.  https://godbolt.org/z/Y7a3M55fe shows it's just a spinlock.  Older MSVC spinning on `lock bts [rdx], 0`, newer MSVC trying an `xchg` but spinning read-only with `pause` if the lock isn't available, with exponential backoff up to 64 `pause` iterations between reads, then linear.  But no fallback to a system call at any point. (Potentially over-engineered for something code should avoid using anyway (non-lock-free atomics), and even 64 `pause` instructions is a *long* time on Skylake and later, like 6400 cycles.)

Comment: IIRC, some commenters have said that the next time MSVC breaks C++ ABI compat, one of the planned changes is to keep the lock outside the `atomic` object like other compilers do ([Where is the lock for a std::atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50298358)).